# ibm i COUNT needed for db table

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a table in the ibm i which is like this:

```
Order#     Amt        Transcodes

123         100           001
123         100           @23
123          100          CWU
```

i have a report that i misunderstood one point. the main report shows all the transcodes which are not '001', and the sub report shows all the 001 only.

That is not what they want. they want the 001 in the sub report ONLY if there are no other codes, iow in our case above, we would not want to call the sub report.

if there was only

```
Order#     Amt        Transcodes

123         100           001
```

then this row we would want.

on the server, I would like to create a view that will contain those rows that have only the 001
and no other of the codes.

```
Select * where transcodes = '001'
```

and order# not in ' here i have to hard code' 'all the codes' ?

or is there a way to do like a count? because they will add codes in the warehouse...

i really want to do a count and then select only when count = 1 but i am not sure how to code or if it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be what you're asking for...

```
select * from yourtable
where transcode = '001'
  and order# not in (select order# from yourtable
                         where transcode <> '001'
                    )
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will produce a listing of all combinations of `order` and `transcode` that are in your table just once (this way you do not need to hard-code anything):

```
SELECT order, MAX(amount), transcode
FROM theTable
GROUP BY order, transcode
HAVING COUNT(order) = 1
```